# matplotlib surface plot with hidden zaxis

Tags: matplotlib, surf

when I change the viewpoint of plot_surface in matplolib in (90,0), the zaxis is not clear, and it's useless in this plot. I want to generate the image same as matlab as below
[matlab surf with view (0,90),with contour lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JBSE.png)
I used matplotlib function imshow can generate matrix image, but there are no lines (similar in contourplot lines)in the image. how can i generate the image with plot_surface in python with a viewpoint of (90,0),bu without zaxis?
[matplotlib with plot_surface,view(90,0),withou lines and zaxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy3RH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [contourf](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) from `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(100), range(100))
Z = X**2+Y**2

plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, [i for i in np.linspace(Z.min(),Z.max(),30)])
plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: Contourf matplotlib]